# Shell script to login as root, provide input through .txt file and execute python script in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I wrote the following script to login as root, change the directory (to where the target scripts are located), open the input text file *"input.txt"* and execute the `python` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
whoami
echo pass**rd | su
cd ~/Scripts
pwd
gedit input.txt
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python test.py\"'
echo "good bye"
```

The above gives me the following output:

```
user4@user-pc-4:~/Desktop$ ./DAT_run.sh
hello
user4
su: must be run from a terminal
/home/user4/Scripts
good bye
```

In addition to the above, I have a `gedit` window that opens the *"input.txt"* and also a `gnome-terminal` window that says:

```
The child process exited normally with status 1.
```

It meets only a part of my requirements, which (in the respective order) are:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Using `su` turn into a root user (security is not a concern here for now, so don't mind passing password as plain text).
3. Change to the directory where target script resides.
4. Open the text file which provides the input to the target script. Hold/wait until the user has saved and closed the text file.
5. Execute the target script.

So, as we can see from the output above, only 3 and partially 4 have been met (doesn't hold or wait until user saves and closes `gedit`). I cannot see the prints from the target program on the terminal window as well. I am a noob and feel like I could very well be missing something here. How can I achieve all my above requirements?

### UPDATE:

After reading the suggestions below, I added a `NOPASSWD:ALL` previlege specification to `user4` in a file `userConfig` which I added to `/etc/sudoers.d/`. Then, I modified my script to  the following:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "hello"
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"cd ~/Scripts;pwd;gedit input.txt;python test.py\"'
echo "good bye"
```

This still gives me the following output:

```
The child process exited normally with status 1.
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Your quoting is funny and the `cd` is repeated. Try `gnome-terminal -e bash -c 'cd ~/Scripts;pwd;gedit input.txt;python test.py'`.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to actually call `sudo` in the updated version.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just set up `sudo` without password, perhaps just for the specific command then?

Processes that read passwords like `su` and `ssh` (and also `sudo`) insist on reading it from a terminal. There are [ways](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) to provide it, but you don't want to jump through those hoops, because [setting up `sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/man.html) is much easier.

---

The other thing is that the part of the script that should run as superuser must be given as argument to the `su`/`sudo`. Because `su`/`sudo` do *not* “switch” the current shell to be superuser, they *execute a child shell*. But the next command in a script will run in the shell that is executing that script after the `su`/`sudo`, including it's child shell, exit, not in that child shell.